# Is 'sorted ascendingly' a valid expression?

Tags: meaning, sort-ordering

Can I use this expression in the sense of 'sorted in ascending order'? The context is programming: sorting a data-structure or results of a query.

Comment: 20 years of database work - never heard it used that way and frankly would find it odd to hear. "An ascending sort" or "sorted in ascending order" are the phrases I would expect to hear, and in technical documents - go for clarity over brevity every time.

Comment: *Sorted ascendingly* sounds perfectly comprehensible, idiomatic, and fine to me.

Comment: @WS2 It sounds like you're alphabetizing a list while you walk up a staircase.

Comment: "ascendingly" isn't in Merriam-Webster or Lexico, so I'd be cautious about using it in formal documents. That said, people would understand it (perhaps after a moment's thought).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It may technically be an acceptable adverb formation, but it is terribly uncomfortable. I would stick with *"sorted in ascending order"*, as it would be readily understood by a larger audience than "ascendingly". Use of "ascendingly" would likely cause unnecessary confusion in your target audience: *i.e. "What did they just say?"*. This would distract from your message.